# Understanding version compatibility of gems with Rails 5 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I'm trying to update my Rails app currently 4.1.4 using:

`gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.rc2', '< 5.1'`

After adding that to my gemfile and running `bundle update rails`

I get the message below (amongst other messages):

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
     activerecord-session_store (~> 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 4.0)

jquery-fileupload-rails (~> 0.4.7) was resolved to 0.4.7, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 3.1)

rails (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0.rc2) was resolved to 5.0.0.rc2, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.0.0.rc2)

rspec-rails (~> 3.5.2) was resolved to 3.5.2, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

Is this saying, that rspec-rails is limiting the upgrade to 3.0? Is this compatible because it is saying that everything is rails 3.0 or greater? I'm trying to figure out what version it is telling me is conflicting the upgrade with this gem.

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason that you're not specifying the specific version of Rails you're after? Something like `gem 'rails', '5.2.1'` (the latest), `gem 'rails', '5.1.6'` (latest 5.1), or `gem 'rails', '5.0.7'` (latest 5.0). I tend to prefer being very specific with such a fundamental component.

Comment: @muistooshort  no reason in particular. i was looking over a tutorial on how to properly upgrade to rails 5 and that was the recommendation